# Magento block attributes

Tags: xml, magento, block

I have a question about Magento blocks. An example of a `product_list` block is shown below:

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” 
        category_id=”3″ 
        column_count=”2″ 
        template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

How do I know the "set"-attributes for a block? like `category_id` and `column_count`?

Does someone have a list or guide to find out set attributes for all block types of Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses magic get and set so you basically can't predict what is set in a given time on program execution step. However you can detect any Varien_Object members and their values by calling

```
print_r($object->getData());
```

or getting the keys of set variables as most of the time the objects are containing objects that are too large to output:

```
print_r(array_keys($object->getData()));
```

that will reveal what variable you can call from object:

```
$object->getVariableKey(); 
$object->getData('variable_key'):
```

And to get all class methods that you can call on given object you can use something like:

```
print_r(get_class_methods($object));
```